# providing a web service: what are best practices for splitting JSON data into two datasets?

Tags: android, iphone, json, web-services, mobile

I have a database and I need to present a data via HTTP using JSON web services. Currently, I'm designing JSON datasets that will be provided as web services. The data from the tables will be aggregated to suite an app needs.

If the data size is large and we will try to download that at once then it might take too much time and an app will not be responsive at start. That's bad. It's well known we should minimize the number of http requests the app will make to download the data. However if we would split the data into small chunks then during every app action step an app will  performe  http requests and that might be unresponsive solution too.

We are talking here about mobile app development, so internet will be exposed over cellular ISP or wifi, so the speed might be quite slow. I understand the split process depends on app workflow process and etc., just curious are there any general guidelines? For example: if JSON data is larger than 1MB then definitely split it into smaller chunks...

Comment: First you should not do internet operation on ui thread second move download data code to service build content provider and cache data in sqlite ... it should help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how your mail read work. You probably have tens of thousands of emails in your account. The app will show the first ones then provide a button at the bottom of the list to display more items. It's a pretty good solution usually to provide a lot of data.

Also @Selvin ideas are just great. Don't use UI thread to download stuff, use a different thread. Services are pretty good for getting data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to create a service which gets started when there is network. All downloaded data can be cached in sqlite and use a content provider to get the data. But it depends on your app.

Sometimes it depends on your UI Screen. For eg. You can create a Listview with load more. On click of it load extra data.

Other way is to create API such as which gives only updates based on timestamp. But its all depends on the app. Just sharing my ideas. Might not be perfect. Others can surely give a better one.